# Enable USBRomService option missing

Tags: retropie

I am trying to run ROMs from my USB. I try to follow the guide, however once in retropie setup/configuration tools, I can't find an option "Enable the USB ROM Transfer Service". I tried looking for this issue, but can't find a single topic. I have 4.4 version, did script update, even did Kernel update. Nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you need that particular `optional` package, which I think that it's not auto-provided with a basic install.
So, ensure you have an internet connection *(not sure if that's necessary since I don't know how RetroPie manages its packages / repos / files)* and do the following:

- **`Retropie Setup`**
- **`Manage packages`**
- **`Manage optional package`**

Scroll the list until you find the usbromservice package. You should be able to install it using the menu and after a reboot you should see it in the `Configuration / tools` menu.

*Please consider that this solution may not be that accurate and probably already exists on the web. I just shared the steps I made to reach my goal. Enjoy!*